# how to calculate text field value without submit button

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am trying to calculate a value without a submit button. If a user enters the weight, height and number of PCs then my code should calculate the value and display it in the total text field automatically without refreshing the page. How can I do that?

This is my calculation: `total = weight * height * no of pcs`

```
<div class="right">
    <label>
        <span>Id :</span>
        <input id="name" type="text" name="roll"  />
    </label>        
    <label>
        <span>material name :</span>
        <input  type="text" name="material" placeholder="material Name" />
    </label>        
    <input name="myprice" type="hidden"  size="10" maxlength="10"  value="1000" readonly/>              
    <label>
        <span>Weight:</span>
        <input name="kg" type="text"  size="10" maxlength="10"  value="0"/>
    </label>
    <label>
        <span> height:</span>
        <input name="mytax" type="text" value="0" size="3" maxlength="4"/>
    </label>
    <label>
        <span> no of pcs :</span>
        <input name="no" type="text" id="no"  value="0" size="3" maxlength="4"/>
    </label>
    <label>
        <span> Total :</span>
        <input name="Total" type="text"   value="0" size="3" maxlength="4"/>
    </label>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you please add the JS code you wrote yourself to the question. At the moment this is a 'write my code for me' request that will likely be closed.

Comment: what have you tries so far?

Comment: look for javascript events like `keyup` , or `keydown` or `keypress`

Comment: Do you think it would be too massive for him to suggest AngularJS?

Comment: i try but not get proper solution

Comment: Try the solution which i answered, its give correct result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this code

**javascript code**

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
                function getOrderTotal() {
                    var iweight= document.myform.weight.value;
                    var iheight= document.myform.iheight.value;
                    var ino= document.myform.no.value;

                    if(!iweight.match(recurrency)) {
                        alert('Please provide an item cost in 0.00 format!');
                    }

                    else {

                        var ifinal=iweight * iheight * ino;

                        );


                        ifinal *= 100;
                        ifinal = Math.ceil(ifinal);
                        ifinal /= 100;
                        if(ifinal) {
                            ifinal = ifinal;
                        }

                        document.getElementById('mytotal').value = ifinal;

                    }
}
```

**html code**

```
<div class="right">
       <label>
        <span> Id :</span>
        <input id="name" type="text" name="roll"  />
    </label>

    <label>
        <span>material name :</span>
        <input  type="text" name="material" placeholder="material Name" />
    </label>



       <label>
        <span>Weight:</span>
     <input name="weight" type="text" id="weight" onchange="getOrderTotal()" size="10" maxlength="10"  value="0"/>
    </label>

    <label>
        <span> height:</span>
       <input name="height" id="height" type="text"  onchange="getOrderTotal()" value="0" size="3" maxlength="4"/>
    </label>


     <label>
        <span> no of pcs :</span>

      <input name="no" type="text" id="no" onchange="getOrderTotal()" value="0" size="3" maxlength="4"/>



    </label>
    <label>
        <span> Total :</span>

      <input name="Total" type="text" id="mytotal"  value="0" size="3" maxlength="4"/>



    </label>


    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You will Use something like this

Include jquery code in your file

```
<script>

    $(document).ready(function() {

        $('input[name="no"]').keyup(function() {

            var kg = $('input[name="kg"]').val();

            var mytax = $('input[name="mytax"]').val();

            var no = $('input[name="no"]').val();

            var total = parseInt(kg) * parseInt(mytax) * parseInt(no);

            $('input[name="Total"]').val(total);

        });

    });

    </script>
```

Hope it will Work

Comment: Also for better result use "keyup" instead of "change"

Answer (score 0):

with jquery

```
 $( '[name="mytax"]' ).change(function() {
     //add here your formula
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

In html add ids to all input fields so that we can easily identify any element:

```
<div class="right">
    <label>
        <span> Id :</span>
        <input id="name" type="text" name="roll"  />
    </label>

    <label>
        <span>material name :</span>
        <input  type="text" name="material" placeholder="material Name" />
    </label>

    <input name="myprice" id="myprice" type="hidden"  size="10" maxlength="10"  value="1000" readonly/>

    <label>
        <span>Weight:</span>
        <input name="kg" id="kg" type="text"  size="10" maxlength="10"  value="0"/>
    </label>

    <label>
        <span> height:</span>
        <input name="mytax" id="mytax"  type="text" value="0" size="3" maxlength="4"/>
    </label>

    <label>
        <span> no of pcs :</span>
        <input name="no"  id="no" type="text" value="0" size="3" maxlength="4"/>
    </label>
    <label>
        <span> Total :</span>
        <input name="total" id="total" type="text"   value="0" size="3" maxlength="4"/>
    </label>
</div>
```

jquery:

1) check if value not then store value in any variable with parseFloat

here we have use `parseFloat` because because price or weight may be in float value.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('#kg, #mytax, #no').change(function () {
        var kg = ($("#kg").val() != "") ? parseFloat($("#kg").val()) : 0;  
        var mytax = ($("#mytax").val() != "") ? parseFloat($("#mytax").val()) : 0;  
        var no = ($("#no").val() != "") ? parseFloat($("#no").val()) : 0;  
        var total = kg * mytax * no;
        $('#total').val(total);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Without using JQuery or any other JavaScript Library, the plain vanilla JavaScript solution will be to tap the "keypress" event.

Here is an example code just to give you the idea:

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function calculate () {
 var a = document.getElementById("a").value;
 var b = document.getElementById("b").value;
 document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = a * b;
}

</script>
</head>
<body>
First Value <input type="text" id="a"></input>
<br>
Second Value <input type="text" id="b" onkeyup="calculate()"></input>
<br>
<div id="result"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

The function `calculate()` is invoked on key press. It takes the value and does the multiplication.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
<div class="right">
    <label>
        <span>Id :</span>
        <input id="name" type="text" name="roll"  />
    </label>        
    <label>
        <span>material name :</span>
        <input  type="text" name="material" placeholder="material Name" />
    </label>        
    <input name="myprice" type="hidden"  size="10" maxlength="10"  value="1000" readonly/>              
    <label>
        <span>Weight:</span>
        <input name="kg" type="text" id="weight" onblur="findTotal()"  size="10" maxlength="10"  value="0"/>
    </label>
    <label>
        <span> height:</span>
        <input name="mytax" type="text" id="height" onblur="findTotal()" value="0" size="3" maxlength="4"/>
    </label>
    <label>
        <span> no of pcs :</span>
        <input name="no" type="text" id="nopc" onblur="findTotal()" value="0" size="3" maxlength="4"/>
    </label>
    <label>
        <span> Total :</span>
        <input name="Total" type="text"  id="total" value="0" size="3" maxlength="4"/>
    </label>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
function findTotal(){
    var weight = document.getElementById('weight').value;
     var height = document.getElementById('height').value;
      var pc = document.getElementById('nopc').value; 


   total = weight * height * pc;
   if(isNaN(total)){
       alert("Please enter only numbers");

   }
     document.getElementById('total').value = total;
}
    </script>
```